# Suddenly an unknow unnamed binary file created under /usr/bin and making more spaw process

Tags: linux, fedora

Suddenly an unknown unnamed binary file created under /usr/bin and making more spawn process and taking more CPU usage. The binary files are created in junk characters. If delete this binary once then it recreate in different name and start load the CPU

Comment: "Have You Tried Turning It Off And On Again?". The problem is so abstract that there is no other usefull advise. At least you can boot from usb or in another runlevel and try to examine the file and look what processes are started with your initialization system (I guess systemd).

Comment: Thanks for the response, i have off it but still running and loading the cpu. Same time how to find which application or script creating this files under /usr/bin. So i can directly delete the source to stop this completely

Comment: Give some examples of `ls -alF` for these files.  What does `ps` or `top` show during heavy CPU usage.  What does `file` give for these "mystery files"?

Comment: "-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 610224 Jan 30 19:05 ajhkyxpfzf*" and File gives this "ajhkyxpfzf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped"